# How can I aggregate rows by orders?

Tags: r

I have a tibble:

```
   itemID order dayR           n
    <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <int>
 1      9     1 2018-01-01     1
 2     11     1 2018-01-01     1
 3     19     1 2018-01-01     2
 4     26     1 2018-01-01    96
 5     26     2 2018-01-01     5
 6     26     3 2018-01-01     1
 7     35     1 2018-01-01   379
 8     35     2 2018-01-01    23
 9     35     3 2018-01-01     4
10     35     4 2018-01-01     1
```

I want to aggregate over the orders and then sum them into `n` to get a unique itemID, so for example the `itemID 26` (`1*96 + 2*5 + 3*1 = 109`):

```
   itemID  dayR           n
    <dbl>  <date>      <int>
 1    26   2018-01-01   109 
...
```

Code for reproduction:

```
structure(list(itemID = c(9, 11, 19, 26, 26, 26, 35, 35, 35, 
                          35), order = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4), dayR = structure(c(17532, 
                                                                                           17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532
                          ), class = "Date"), n = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 96L, 5L, 1L, 379L, 23L, 
                                                    4L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                 "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group_by()` and `summarize()`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(itemID, dayR) %>% 
  summarize(n=sum(n*order))
```

Output:

```
  itemID dayR           n
   <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1      9 2018-01-01     1
2     11 2018-01-01     1
3     19 2018-01-01     2
4     26 2018-01-01   109
5     35 2018-01-01   441
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `%*%`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(itemID, dayR) %>% 
    summarise(n = c(n %*% order), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  itemID dayR           n
   <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1      9 2018-01-01     1
2     11 2018-01-01     1
3     19 2018-01-01     2
4     26 2018-01-01   109
5     35 2018-01-01   441
```